# Emulator: Process finished with exit code 3; getting this error in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Just built my new PC, I get this error while trying to use the emulator. I am extremely disappointed. I really need help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this too. I uninstalled and reinstalled the Q SDK and also did a Windows Update which installed a roll-up for July 2019.
Now it works.